# mocking a superclass method with EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I have a class hierarchy as follows:

```
public class Parent {
    public int parentMethod(...) {...}
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public int childMethod(...) {...}
}
```

I'd like to mock out an instance of the `Child` class, but `parentMethod` is called on that object frequently (as well as `childMethod`). The default EasyMock behavior when I try to use `expect()` on a `parentMethod` call is to use the *real* `parentMethod`, but that doesn't work because there's a bunch of state in the Parent class which I don't want to mock out. Is there any way to mock it out using `createMockBuilder` or any other EasyMock API?

Comment: Try JMockit Expectations API

Answer (score 1):

I think a partial mock is what you're thinking of.

Partial Mocks allow you to have a real object that has specific functionality (specific methods) mocked out. So the real state would be used when the `parentMethod` was called, but the `childMethod` could be mocked.

You then set your expectations and verify the mock in the same way as you would with a fully mocked object.

In terms of creating one in EasyMock, something like this will do the trick:

```
    final IMockBuilder<Child> mockBuilder = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(Child.class);
    mockBuilder.addMockedMethod("childMethod");
    final Child mockedChild = mockBuilder.createMock();

    EasyMock.expect(mockedChild.childMethod()).andReturn(1);
    EasyMock.replay(mockedChild);

    //Whatever else happens in your test

    EasyMock.verify(mockedChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand from your questions. Is you don't want to mock parentClass{ }.

You can try this.

```
objenesis = new ObjenesisStd(); // or ObjenesisSerializer
 obj_1 = objenesis.newInstance(Child.class);
 method = obj_1.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("childMethod",NULL);
 method.setAccessible(true);
 method.invoke(obj_1,NULL);
```

With this approach you can Mock only child class without dependency of any parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Coming in six years after the original question, I just ran into what I think OP was really asking: How to mock a subclass and have all methods in the parent class also be mocked? The other answers here, dealing with partial mocks, are off the mark if that's the case.

Anyway, this just happened to me. The parent's real method got called when I mocked the subclass. The answer? The parent's method was declared `final` so EasyMock couldn't override it in the mocked subclass. Removing the `final` declaration cleared it up and that method is now mocked.

Now, the suggestions regarding partial mocks weren't for naught: I figured this out by attempting to mock just that method via a partial mock, and that's when EasyMock told me it couldn't do it. When just using the blanket `createMock` approach, it silently behaved in the manner previously described.

Hopefully that helps somebody in the future.

Cheers,
Steve